# How to do batch insert with an autonumber in JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, autonumber

Previously i had some experience with MS Access and now i am doing JDBC, in Java of course. In MS Access Databases i can have a AutoNumber field, which is very convenient for generating primary keys. I would like to do the same in Java. However, after digging in SO(and google of course) for a few days, what i can find is just some very handy way. One of them is to firstly get the largest primary key( say N ) in the table, and then you insert the latest record with a key of (N+1). This works, i guess, but not efficient. Can any SO genius help me?

Comment: I think, if you fire your insert query through JDBC without specifying primary key (which is set AutoNumber in database), it should insert new record with automatically generated key.

Comment: I believe you want to insert records, and then getting the generated keys, if that's your case, I think you shall ignore the batching mode.

Comment: no wonder nobody answers a couple of similar questions, i'm an idiot missing this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a similar capability: auto increment.  Just add this to your key fields and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which bit you are stuck on

but in MySql Auto number is basically.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name 
( 
   id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
   Value INTEGER
)
```

To use it from something like Java, just skip it in the sql e.g.

```
Insert table_name(Value) Values(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not really related to `JDBC`.

You have to create the table in `mysql` with an auto-incrementing column (Take a look at `INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` for the column specifications).

Then in `JDBC` you just ignore that column when you insert data (like it didn't exist) and the database will take care of it!